# Number sequence puzzle

Tags: sequences-and-series, puzzle

So recently I was asked this question in a written aptitude test but I could not answer. Find the next number in the sequence:

1 1 2 3 10 13 23 41 . . .

I have tried a lot of things but nothing seems to work. Any one got any idea?

Comment: Fibonacci numbers in base 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*: Think of these numbers as written in base 5. What are the correspondent numbers in base 10?